# validate the form before stripe checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments

When using  [stipe checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), how can I proceed if I want the button to first validate the whole form before showing the credit card payment popup?

In other words, how can I have the "pay" button be more of (if form is ok, then proceed to payment).

Is this possible with checkout or should I build my own form with stripe.js and ignore checkout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical about the "pay" button; it's just an element to which you've tied some JavaScript.

Implementing Stripe Checkout is nothing more than a call to `StripeCheckout.open`.

If you want to validate your form contents before showing the Checkout overlay, then you just rewrite your JavaScript (or your server-side code—whichever way makes more sense for your application) to do validation before you call for the Checkout overlay.

For more details, see the [Checkout API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#api).